# Filter words in MongoDb in javaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

im building a chatbot to filter questions and i would like to know how to filter the search of my MongoDb with the input of the user.

By now I have this

I want to get all the results that match a word with a word of the variable words.

```
 let text = this.messageEvent.data.text

var words= text.split(" ")
this.fetchDataFromDataSource({ channel: this.channel, collectionName: "62a985781cd96396e4e1cba3_test", filter: {
   input:"$KeywordGroup1",
   
 } }).then((result) => {

            console.log(result)
  })
```

and my database looks like this [image: database]

i would like to filter with the input of the user.
if a user writes price it should return the 3 entries of the database, but if the user writes any other thing it shouldn't return anything.

I dont want to use find since it could give more than one entry on the db with that keygroup

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is something with the elemMatch could help you?

```
db.collection.find({
  "data": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$eq": "price"
    }
  }
})
```

Find the playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OcdgdPrvQz5).

Comment: I dont want to use find since it could give more than one entry on the db with that keygroup

Comment: Instead you can use an *aggregation* with the `$match` operator. 

See this link: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/mongodb/mongodb-aggregate-match-in-array/#:~:text=the%20%24eq%20operator.-,Use%20%24match%20With%20%24all%20to%20Find%20Matching%20Documents,in%20an%20Array%20in%20MongoDB&text=The%20%24all%20is%20equivalent%20to,contain%20Java%20and%20Python%20elements.